# Select only one region at a time

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I am using [jVectorMap](http://jvectormap.com/) to display an interactive map. Currently I can select multiple regions at the same time, but my requirement is to only allow the selection of one at a time. How can this be done?

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    backgroundColor: '#0099FF',
    /* Hover color for each state */
    hoverColor: '#FCEF06',
    hover: {
        stroke: 'black',
        "stroke-width": 2,
        fill:'#FCEF06'
    },
    onRegionClick: function(event, code)
    {
        alert(code);
    },
    regionsSelectable: true,
    regionStyle: {
        fill:'black',
        selected: {
            fill: 'red'
        }
    },
});
```

```
<div id="world-map" style="width:750px; height:380px; float:left;"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along with the `regionsSelectable` property, there is also a `regionsSelectableOne` property to go with it.

Setting `regionsSelectable` to true lets you select the regions and setting `regionsSelectableOne` to true only allows one to be selected at a time.

[jVectorMap Documentation](http://jvectormap.com/documentation/javascript-api/jvm-map/)

```
$('#world-map').vectorMap({
    backgroundColor: '#0099FF',
    /* Hover color for each state */
    hoverColor: '#FCEF06',
    hover: {
        stroke: 'black',
        "stroke-width": 2,
        fill:'#FCEF06'
    },
    onRegionClick: function(event, code)
    {
        alert(code);
    },
    regionsSelectable: true,
    regionsSelectableOne: true, //add this line here
    regionStyle: {
        fill:'black',
        selected: {
            fill: 'red'
        }
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

See this tutorial example

http://jvectormap.com/examples/regions-selection/

You should see on

```
regionStyle: {
      initial: {
        fill: '#B8E186'
      },
      selected: {   // here
        fill: '#F4A582'
      }
    },

onRegionSelected: function(){
      if (window.localStorage) {
        window.localStorage.setItem(
          'jvectormap-selected-regions',
          JSON.stringify(map.getSelectedRegions())
        );
      }
    },
```

Hope it helps you